# I want to remove the home page header image from all other pages

Tags: code, codex

I want to remove the home page header image from all other pages. When you click an individual article, the feature image and header image blend into each other in an unflattering way.There needs to be separation between the images or have the header image remain on the home page only.

www.mybesthelperblog.wordpress.com

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the call to the header image in your `header.php` file with the following:

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
   // Call to Header Image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your current themes header.php file in when call the logo there put the condition. for example like this.

```
<?php 
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    twentysixteen_the_custom_logo();
    }
?>
```

i hope is useful.